# Excel Vba - Run-Time Error 1004 when try to assign a Series Formula to Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I stuck with run-time error code 1004 : Application define or object define.

When I try to get all Series value of all chart and I need to paste it to a cells to easy monitor. Everything work fine, but it stuck when I try to give cell a value equal with Series Value.

Example:

```
Dim xchart As ChartObject
For Each xchart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

Dim ser As Series

For Each ser In xchart.Chart.SeriesCollection
 ......
    Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = ser.Formula ' Run-time Error Occur
 ....
Next ser    
Next xchart
```

Could anybody help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
Sheet1.Range("a1").Value = "'" & ser.Formula
```

to have a text value stored in cell

otherwise it would interpret it as a (unknown) formula